# Dart remove range of date from List

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of dates and I want to remove the specific date range don't know how to remove it. Basically I want to remove all the time after `endTime`

```
  var endTime;
  var startTime;
  var today = now.day;
  var startOpeningHr = 06;
  var endOpeningHr = 18;
  endTime = getDateandTiming(today, endOpeningHr);
  startTime = getDateandTiming(today, startOpeningHr);


  var dates = [2021-07-24 14:30:00.000, 2021-07-24 15:00:00.000, 2021-07-24 
             15:30:00.000, 2021-07-24 16:00:00.000, 2021-07-24 16:30:00.000, 2021-07- 
             24 17:00:00.000, 2021-07-24 17:30:00.000, 2021-07-24 18:00:00.000, 2021- 
             07-24 18:30:00.000, 2021-07-24 19:00:00.000, 2021-07-24 19:30:00.000, 
             2021-07-24 20:00:00.000, 2021-07-24 20:30:00.000, 2021-07-24 
             21:00:00.000, 2021-07-24 21:30:00.000, 2021-07-24 22:00:00.000, 2021-07- 
             24 22:30:00.000, 2021-07-24 23:00:00.000, 2021-07-24 23:30:00.000, 2021- 
             07-25 00:00:00.000, 2021-07-25 00:30:00.000, 2021-07-25 01:00:00.000, 
             2021-07-25 01:30:00.000, 2021-07-25 02:00:00.000, 2021-07-25 
             02:30:00.000, 2021-07-25 03:00:00.000]
  
   
getDateandTiming(dateType, startOpening) {
    var checkDate =
        DateTime(now.year, now.month, dateType, startOpening, 0, 0);
    return checkDate;
}
```

I have used the `removewhere` but it not working as expected

```
 dates.removeWhere((element){
     if (endTime.isAfter(element)) {
          return null;
     }
     return element;
 });
```

Comment: removeWhere should return a boolean which indicate if the element should be removed or not. So return true if the element should be removed and false if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the solution, Suppose you need to remove after endTime just use `removeWhere` in loop in this way

```
 dates.removeWhere((element) {
     if (endTime.isAfter(element)) {
           return false;
     }
     return true;
  });
```

Comment: @jamesdlin I tried yours but i'm getting the blank result while doing `dates.removeWhere(endTime.isAfter)` this

Comment: Oops, you're right; sorry, I was the one who got mixed up.